Set breakpoints to all functions inside specific directory in Visual Studio Code
I'm exploring PHP application that uses Laravel framework and I want to start debugging each time when execution returns to application code (inside "app" directory) and skip debugging all code of the framework (inside "vendor" directory).
There is "Function breakpoint" in VSCode but it seems not supported any kind of substring matching (regexp doesn't work too).
Is it possible to do something to debug only application code excluding all other code?
I expect debugger stops on every function/method of application code.
